# responsive youtube video inside of "TV" background container?

Tags: javascript, css, video, youtube, embed

I have a "container" image of a TV screen, and I would like to "embed" a youtube video inside of the image container so it appears as if the video is playing on television screen. I do not know exactly what this is called, as my searches have turned up little information. Basically I want the video to resize with the container and fit it exactly at all times. I can not determine if this would be better accomplished with javascript or CSS -- are there any good plugins to accomplish this sort of thing?

My current code:

```
  <style>
    .macbook-wrapper{
      background: url('../img/content/home/macbook.png') no-repeat;
      max-width: 1034px;
      max-height: 543px;
    }
  </style>
  <center>
    <div class="macbook-wrapper">
      <iframe width="1034" height="543" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/**removed**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </center>
```

---

I have set the max-width and height of the container to the dimensions of the macbook screen image. using `fitvid.js` the youtube iframe matches the size of the wrapper, however I cannot see the background image. How can I scale the youtube video down so that it just fits the background image screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using jQuery or not, but Take a look at Fitvids.js (http://fitvidsjs.com/). I have used it on almost all my responsive projects and it works really well.

**UPDATE**
I set up a working demo on Code pen at http://codepen.io/micahmills/pen/kxdfI. I didn't have a transparent PNG of a macbook but you get the idea. The code is:

**HTML**

```
      <iframe width="854" height="510" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Rio16skrp2w?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .macbook-wrapper{
  background: url('http://pngimg.com/upload/tv_PNG477.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 814px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.macbook-wrapper .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
  width: 97.5%;
  max-width: 1009px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: I am using jQuery. How do you get the video to match the size of the image container with fitVids?

Comment: If you put your video embed in wrapper that is the appropriate size the video will scale to that wrapper

Comment: @micahmills: I updated my original post -- using fitvids.js, the image is not positioned/scaled inside the container how I would like it to be. How can I make it appear as if it resides on the screen in the center of my background-image?